# AutoFixture sometimes failing to generate a value for a property marked with RangeAttribute

Tags: asp.net-core, autofixture, nsubstitute

I have a very strange behaviour in my testing code at the moment... It all started with decorating a string property with the `RangeAttribute`. I'm unit testing model validation in ASP.NET Core using the `Validator` class, so in the example below `MyClass` is a request object.

As i've understood AutoFixture will take into consideration the attribute a property is marked with. This is what the (pseudo) code looks like:

```
private void RunTest()
        {
            var sut = Fixture.Freeze<MyClass>();
            sut.MyPropery = "12345";
            // all tests from here on fails randomly
        }

        private class MyClass
        {
            [Required]
            [Range(10000, 99999)]
            public string MyPropery { get; set; }
        }
```

*Sometimes*, the value generated is 10000 (woho!), and *sometimes* I get the following error, and i'm not sure why:

> AutoFixture was unable to create an instance from
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.RangedNumberRequest, most likely because it
>   has no public constructor, is an abstract or non-public type.

I'm writing a unit test using `"AutoFixture.AutoNSubstitute": "3.49.0"`

Any ideas what might be wrong here?

Comment: Is this actual for the [latest version](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/releases/tag/v3.50.2)?

Comment: Would it be possible to provide an example that reproduces this behavior?

Comment: @SergeyShushlyapin what do you mean?

Comment: @NikosBaxevanis Updated with some example code

Comment: What is the expected behavior of applying the `[Range]` attribute to a `string` property?

Comment: @SergeyShushlyapin To validate that the value can be parsed into an integer *and* the value falls into the range.

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/issues/453/) issue, and more specifically [this](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/issues/453#issuecomment-149463476) comment.

Comment: @NikosBaxevanis Yes that link is interesting. It seems very related to the problem, and in my case it ends up picking the third constructor since i'm using strings. I solved it by *not* asking AutoFixture to generate it for me, but instead setting the value manually with the `Build` and `With` syntax.

Comment: @JimAho, I'm not sure there's much we can do, since [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679255.aspx) overload you're using takes any type. What happens if one applies that attribute over, say, a `Version` property?